# make redis client available in route

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, require, node-modules

In my **app.js**, i have constructed a **redis client**:

```
var redis = require('redis'),
  redisClient = redis.createClient(6379, 'localhost');

...

module.exports = {
  app:app,
  redisClient:redisClient
}
```

I need to use the redis client in my other module, which is **routes/index.js**. here, i tried including it like so:

```
var redisClient = require('../app').redisClient;
```

Unfortunatly, it is undefined. 
Should i just require it in the index.js like i did in the app.js, and create a new instance here? Or what could i change to make it work?

Comment: All the code you posted is correct. It should work. Please post some more code, other files, folder structure, etc.

Comment: It looks like somewhere in that file you might be already using `exports` to export something different. As a rule of thumb, if you use `module.exports` in a file do not use `exports` again (and the other way around)